# Custom Email Headers in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, email-headers

I can't seem to locate the method within the Laravel 4 docs/Email API where I can add custom headers to an email.

For example:

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->to('foo@example.com', 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!');
    $message->headers('X-Tags', 'tag1 tag2 tag3');
});
```

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know there's no way to add custom headers without reaching in to Swift Mailer.

Try something like this.

```
$message->getSwiftMessage()->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-Tags', 'tag1 tag2 tag3');
```

It doesn't look pretty but from looking through the source that should do the trick.

---

As pointed out in the comments below the `getSwiftMessage` method isn't required as there is an `__call` magic method on the `Illuminate\Mail\Message` class that I overlooked.

```
$message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-Tags', 'tag1 tag2 tag3');
```

Comment: The `getSwiftMessage()` method, is that one needed? I got a good result with just `$Message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader()`

Comment: Ah yeah it's not needed. Didn't notice the magic method there that fires the methods on the `Swift_Message` class. I have updated my answer.

Comment: +2 This is great!!!!! I am using this with Mandrill seamlessly and can pull of stats on emails and can really customise emails. http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21688056-Using-SMTP-Headers-to-customize-your-messages