# Add headers in mail function laravel 5

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I am updating code from laravel 4 to laravel 5

In laravel 4 there is mail functionality implemented with some code like below

```
Mail::send('emailtemplate.sample', $content_data, function ($message) use ($to_mail, $email_data, $from_name) {
            $message->from('admin@domain.com', 'admin')->to($to_mail)->subject($email_data->subject);                
            $headers = $message->getHeaders();
            $headers->addTextHeader('X-MC-PreserveRecipients', 'false');
        });
```

I don't know how to replace `$headers = $message->getHeaders();` and `$headers->addTextHeader('X-MC-PreserveRecipients', 'false');` in laravel 5 mail functionality

If anyone knows, then please suggest

Comment: is the debug mode set to true?

Comment: Are you getting an error when you attempt this code? A quick glance at Laravel 5's code seems to indicate these same methods are still available and should work the same.

Comment: @jszobody, I have not tried still, but is there any reference when I can look into it to just confirm myself about this is still true and working?

Comment: @NishantSolanki, yes it is. but I haven't run my email function still. as I am missing its code(this header one) itself

Comment: The `getHeaders()` method is being called on `Swift_Message` which isn't part of Laravel, it's a third-party component. So even though Laravel 5 has changed, Swift hasn't and should continue working like before. You can browse the source code to confirm. Go test your code and come back if you experience a problem.

Comment: give this a try .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465746/custom-email-headers-in-laravel-4

Comment: @jszobody, yes its good clarification. I have just tested and it works as you mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jszobody mentioned,

The `getHeaders()` method is being called on `Swift_Message` which isn't part of Laravel, it's a third-party component. So even though Laravel 5 has changed, Swift hasn't and should continue working like before.