# Set SendGrid category in Laravel's mail library

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5, sendgrid

I'm sending an email in Laravel via SendGrid using the configuration suggested in [SendGrid's docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/laravel.html).

Just to provide an example of how it looks now:

```
Mail::send('emails.demo', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->to('jane@example.com', 'Jane Doe')->subject('This is a demo!');
});
```

The email itself works fine, but I'd like to add a SendGrid category. I've accomplished this in past non-Laravel projects using the `addCategory()` method in [this repo](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php).

My question: Is there an easy way to add a SendGrid category just using the Laravel mail library, or does it make more sense to just use the SendGrid PHP library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use the library, even though it isn't that pretty.

Comment: That's what I wound up going with. Realized I was bending over backwards just to save myself like 3 lines of code.

Comment: For those who prefer to not add a library for this feature alone, see this if you're using SMTP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42780012/1849081

Answer (score 2):

There are two different ways of doing this depending on your `MAIL_MAILER` *(or `MAIL_DRIVER` in Laravel <7)*.

### When `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp`:

```php
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('mail')
            ->from('')
            ->subject('')
            ->withSwiftMessage(function($message) {
                $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader(
                    'X-SMTPAPI', json_encode(['category' => 'testing category'])
                );
            });
    }
```

Read more about the `smtp` driver: https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/laravel#adding-a-category-or-custom-field

### When `MAIL_DRIVER=sendgrid`:

```php
   use Sichikawa\LaravelSendgridDriver\SendGrid;

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('mail')
            ->from('')
            ->subject('')
            ->sendgrid(['category' => 'testing category']);
    }
```

Read more about the `sendgrid` driver: https://github.com/s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver

Comment: Works for me. This should be the correct answer. Sendgrid now have a laravel page too.

Comment: Nice they added it to their documentation https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/laravel/ I had contact with sengrid to get to this solution great help from their side!

Comment: Just a heads up that Laravel 9 now uses withSymfonyMessage instead of withSwiftMessage. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding an X-SMTPAPI header that contains the categories, but Laravel doesn't expose custom headers so you have to drop down to SwiftMailer directly. For an example, take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465746/custom-email-headers-in-laravel-4)