# laravel 5.3 sendgrid categories

Tags: laravel, email

In laravel 5.2 this worked just fine, but since migrating to 5.3 i'm having issues getting the category sent in my email.

```
public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('mail.enquiry')
            ->getSwiftMessage()->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-SMTPAPI', json_encode(array("category" => array(env('BUSINESS_NAME')))))
            ->subject('Website Enquiry')
            ->to(env('MAIL_DEFAULT_TO_EMAIL'), env('MAIL_DEFAULT_TO_NAME'))
            ->from(env('MAIL_DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL'), env('MAIL_DEFAULT_FROM_NAME'))
            ->replyTo(\Request::get('email'), \Request::get('full_name'));
    }
```

i get this error

```
BadMethodCallException in Mailable.php line 525:
Method [getSwiftMessage] does not exist on mailable.
```

every thing in this code works fine, but breaks as soon as I add this line:

```
    ->getSwiftMessage()->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-SMTPAPI', json_encode(array("category" => array(env('BUSINESS_NAME')))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve what you're after you can use the `withSwiftMessage()` method.

This method takes a callback which will be passed the instance of `SwiftMessage`:

```
->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) {
    $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-SMTPAPI', json_encode(array("category" => array(env('BUSINESS_NAME')))));
})
```

So your method would look something like:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('mail.enquiry')
        ->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) {
            $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-SMTPAPI', json_encode(array("category" => array(env('BUSINESS_NAME')))));
        })
        ->subject('Website Enquiry')
        ->to(env('MAIL_DEFAULT_TO_EMAIL'), env('MAIL_DEFAULT_TO_NAME'))
        ->from(env('MAIL_DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL'), env('MAIL_DEFAULT_FROM_NAME'))
        ->replyTo(\Request::get('email'), \Request::get('full_name'));
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

*Since I visited this question when looking for a solution on Laravel 8 I'm adding some more info to the already accepted answer:*

In Laravel 8 now you can follow instructions here: https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/laravel/ and check section titled "Adding a category or custom field".

It does still use `withSwifthMessage()` - more info for this on laravel's site: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#customizing-the-swiftmailer-message

The gist of it is simillar to the already accepted answer, but provides some nice helpers too and clearer code:

In your `build()` function:

```
$headerData = [
    'category' => 'category',
    'unique_args' => [
        'variable_1' => 'abc'
    ]
];

$header = $this->asString($headerData);

$this->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) use ($header) {
      $message->getHeaders()
              ->addTextHeader('X-SMTPAPI', $header);
});

return $this->view('emails.test')
                ->from($address, $name)
```

Helpers:

```
private function asJSON($data)
{
    $json = json_encode($data);
    $json = preg_replace('/(["\]}])([,:])(["\[{])/', '$1$2 $3', $json);

    return $json;
}


private function asString($data)
{
    $json = $this->asJSON($data);

    return wordwrap($json, 76, "\n   ");
}
```

Might be useful to someone.